# How change the order of overlapping line in line chart Power BI

Tags: powerbi, linegraph

When we want to emphasize one line with different color (my case "green"),
set the rest of the lines as "grey" , like below :

[image]

But the Problem the grey one which don't want to be emphasized
covering the main line like the arrangement in Power Point "Front" or "Backward"

How to **arrange the order of line** to decide which one on the top that won't be hidden by another lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following workaround:

- move the measure you want to emphasize to the top;
- then save and reopen the pbix file (or simply go to another page and then back)

It should now bring the green line to the front.

Users have requested this capability as an explicit feature, but Microsoft hasn't implemented it yet, as far as I know.

Comment: thankyou RADO , thats a sad news,not flexible as Excel but also not programmatic like R ggplot , deadlock.

Comment: Testing this in February 2021, after adjusting the order of measures as explained above, it is sufficient to switch to a different page and come back (no need to save and reopen the pbix file).